# Pre-image of Measurable sets are measurable under the mapping h(x,y)=x-y

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

I am trying to prove the following statement:

> For $h:\mathbb{R}^2\longrightarrow \mathbb{R}$, given by $h(x,y)=x-y$, if $L\in\mathcal{M}(\mathbb{R})$, where $\mathcal{M}(\mathbb{R})$ denotes the set of Lebesgue measurable sets in $\mathbb{R}$, then $h^{-1}(L)\in \mathcal{M}(\mathbb{R}^2)$.

Here's the proof I came up with:

Take $L\in\mathcal{M}(\mathbb{R})$, we have that:
\begin{align*}
h^{-1}(L)& =\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2: (x-y)\in L\}\\
& =\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2: x=z+y, \forall z\in L\}\\
& =\{(x,x-z)\in\mathbb{R}^2: z\in L\}\\
\end{align*}

Now, let $F:L\times\mathbb{R}\longrightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$ be the linear transformation (shearing map in this case) associated with the matrix $A=\begin{bmatrix}1 &1\\0 & 1\end{bmatrix} $ in the standard basis for $\mathbb{R}^2$. Clearly, $F$ is injective. Notice, since $L\in\mathcal{M}(\mathbb{R})$, then $L\times\mathbb{R}\in\mathcal{M}(\mathbb{R^2})$, and since $F$ is injective then: $$\left(h^{-1}(L)=F(L\times \mathbb{R})\right)\in \mathcal{M}(\mathbb{R}^2)$$

Is this proof correct? Are there faster ways of going about this by wrapping $h^{-1}(L)$ in $\mathcal{G}_{\delta}$ or some other method?

Comment: This is the best method as far as I would say. Can you think of another method?

Comment: I couldn't, but my professor did mention there is potentially another way of going about this.

Comment: Neither can I think of any method. Get back if you get to know the professor's method.